# How to view the schema of a table in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

In MySQL it's pretty easy, just run **DESC tablename;** query and it shows the structure but *doesn't work for SQL Server*.

I tried the same thing.

Comment: SSMS (Management Studio) and Visual Studio have this built-in.  Both will show you the table visually, or you can script it into a CREAT TABLE command, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know all the basic metadata about a table, you can use [sp_help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

`exec sp_help 'dbo.SomeTable'`

There are other catalog views like sys.tables, sys.columns, etc that you can query for specific details.

But most people use a GUI like SQL Server Management Studio that will display the table metadata in a treeview, or schema diagram.

Comment: Adding one can select an object name in an SSMS query window and press the alt-F1 shortcut key to execute `sp_help` on the object.